# Odd and Even Number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error when calculating odd and even numbers in range 2008 2009 2010 and 2011. Actually this code for calculate the winner of team A, every odd year the team will win. That why, in my code when its odd year, it will +1.

```
i = 0
sum = 0

n = list(map(int, input("Year : ").split()))
for i in n :
    if i % 2 != 0 :
        sum += 1
    else :
        sum = 0
print("Win :", sum)

# Input
2008 2009 2010 2011
# Output
1 (This is the problem, it should be 2 wins but i dont know why the output is always 1)
```

Comment: `else: sum = 0` seems wrong, no?

Comment: I think not, im not give a value for even number

Comment: for the first iteration, sum = 0. `i` is even, so sum = 0. In the second iteration, `i` is odd. hence, sum +=1 and sum is now 1. In the third iteration, i is even. So now in the else block you assign sum to 0. Meaning, sum = 0. in the next iteration, i is odd hence sum += 1. But since sum = 0, sum is changed to 1. and that's how you get the 1 output. Basically, your else block changes sum to 0 when an even year is encountered and the whole progress is lost.

Comment: @illusion Thank you for explain it, i removed that sum = 0 and it is work like i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need `else :sum = 0`. You can continue with

```py
i = 0
sum = 0

n = list(map(int, input("Year : ").split()))
for i in n :
    if i % 2 != 0 :
        sum += 1
  
print("Win :", sum)
```

Comment: I see, i tried it as soon as you answered  and yeah its worked like i want. Thank you for help me ...

Answer (score 0):

A juanpa_arrivillaga tried to get you to notice, when you encounter an even year, you are setting the sum to 0.  When it's an odd year, you are incrementing sum.  Whenever you set the sum to 0, it undoes any incrementing you did in the previous iterations of the loop.  Try printing sum out at the end of every loop and see if it says what you think it should say.

Answer (score 0):

```
else :
    sum = 0
```

This statement is resetting the value of sum back to zero.
Hence you can simply discard it.

Comment: Yes, i removed it

Comment: then it should be giving correct result now